# Modify the code (lapply function) in R

Tags: r, lapply

How can I modify this code (or add more functions) in a way that

1. I could have the name of each element of responseList in summaries instead of having [[1]], [[2]],....
2. How can I extract the hp:am with the p-value less than 0.05
3. How can I have the normality plot of residual (but all histograms in just one page)

Example:

```
responseList <- names(mtcars)[-c(4,9)]
modelList <- lapply(responseList, function(resp) {
    mF <- formula(paste(resp, " ~ hp * am"))
    aov(mF, data = mtcars)
})
summaries <- lapply(modelList, summary)
resid <- lapply(modelList, resid)
normal <- lapply(resid, function(x) shapiro.test(x))
```

Comment: `modelList <- lapply(mtcars[-c(4,9)], function(x) aov(x ~ hp*am, data=mtcars) )` maybe? Loop over the columns instead of the names.

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks so much, you are right, do you have any idea for the second and third questions?

Comment: i think you can get away without loops here: try `summary(av <- aov(as.matrix(mtcars[-c(4,9)]) ~ hp * am, data=mtcars))`; then `resid(av)` . And so for the plot `ggplot(melt(resid(av)), aes(value)) + 
  facet_wrap( ~ Var2, scales="free") + geom_density()`
`

Comment: @ user20650, thanks so much, great suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ 1]

```
modelList <- lapply(mtcars[-c(4,9)], function(x) aov(x ~ hp*am, data=mtcars) )
```

[2]

```
df2 <- plyr::ldply(modelList, function(x) summary(x)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]])
names(df2) <- c(attr(modelList[[1]]$terms, "term.labels"), "residuals")
```

[3]

```
res.list <- lapply(modelList, '[[', "residuals")

par(mfrow=c(5,2), oma=c(0,0,0,0))
lapply(res.list, hist)
```

[image]

Comment: great thanks so much, just some questions. For the second function how I can modify your code to have the real name of columns (hp, am,..) instead of V1, V2,V3, V4. Also, How can I modify your third function to have the name of each variable instead of X[[i]]?

Comment: The second question is straightforward. Instead of `lapply(res.list, hist)`, go with `lapply(names(res.list), function(x) hist(res.list[[x]], main=x))`.

Comment: @ Adam Quek, thanks, but the function does not work.

Comment: Does not work as in? Also, did you use the `modelList` in the answer? The names of `res.list` inherits that of the `modelList`